# Iteration controlled loop not working correctly

Tags: c

The following should generate 2 random numbers between 0 and 100, that follow certain rules.

Those rules being:

*Neither can be 0

*Num1 must be larger than Num2

*And Num1 must be divisible by Num2 (The num1 % num2 bit)

Currently the loop works correctly for the first two points, but not the last one. It is still generating numbers where num1 is not divisible by num2. Whats gone wrong?

```
do {
        if (num1 == 0) {
            num1 = rand()%100;
        }
        else if(num2 == 0) {
            num2 = rand()%100;
        }
        else if (num1 < num2) {
            num2 = rand()%100;
        }
        else if(num1 % num2 != 0) {
            num2 = rand()%100;
        }
        a++;
        printf("Loop no.:%d %d mod %d = %d %d / %d \n",a,num1,num2,num1%num2,num1,num2);
    } while(num1 < num2 && (num1%num2 != 0) && num1 != 0 && num2 != 0);
```

Comment: `num1 = rand()%100;` may still generate 0

Comment: If neither of the conditions is satisfied, `numX` won't change. So it will loop forever

Comment: Why are you testing the conditions in two places? If you're going to use the generate-then-test method, generate the numbers, then test them, and regenerate them if they fail. But put the tests in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all conditions met, your `while`-condition should actually be something like `while(num1 < num2 || (num1%num2 != 0) || num1== 0 || num2 == 0)`. If you connect the conditions by `&&`, the loop will end once one of the conditions is not met, e.g. when `num1` is not divisible by `num2`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done more efficiently.

Start with one number,

```
num2 = rand()%50 + 1;
```

This will be the lower number. If it is bigger that 50, there is no possible second number.
Then, calculate how many numbers are possible for `num1`. Since `num1` must be a multiple of `num2`, and less than or equal to 100, and it may not be the same as `num2`:

```
int nnum1 = 100/num2 - 1;
```

The, just pick one:

```
num1 = (rand()%nnum1 + 2)*num2;
```

[Live demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/053d8d20591f4688)